# Como convierto ciertos números de una matriz en símbolos en lenguaje C

Tags: c

En esta función recibo como parámetro una matriz de NxN que solo tiene como valores 1 o 0, y tengo que cambiar los 1 por * y los 0 por espacios en blanco. El programa sale bien cuando la matriz es de 3x3, pero cuando es de 4x4,5x5,6x6 no se cambian los 1 y 0, solo se imprime un *.

```
 int MatrizPintada(int filas,int cols,int matriz[filas][cols])
    {
        char natriz[filas][cols]; //creo matriz char para guardar los caraceteres '*' y ' '
    
        for(int i = 0; i< filas; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
            {
                matriz[i][j];
    
                if(matriz[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    natriz[i][j] = '*';
                }
                else if(matriz[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    natriz[i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
    
        for(int i = 0; i< filas; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
            {
                printf("%c ",natriz[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> En esta función recibo como parámetro una matriz de NxN que solo tiene como valores 1 o 0

Entonces sabemos que una celda tendrá o `1` o `0` y no cualquier otra cosa.

Con este dato en mente se puede simplificar la lógica

```
for(int i = 0; i< filas; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
    {
        matriz[i][j];

        if(matriz[i][j] == 1)
        {
            natriz[i][j] = '*';
        }
        else 
        {
            natriz[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

El problema de poner un `else if`, aparte de una comprobación innecesaria, estás dejando de lado la posibilidad de que el dato no sea `0` o `1`, es decir, te faltaría un `else` final. Como esta no es una posibilidad lo mejor es simplificar el algoritmo

> El programa sale bien cuando la matriz es de 3x3, pero cuando es de 4x4,5x5,6x6 no se cambian los 1 y 0, solo se imprime un *

Puede que la culpa la tenga el VLA o Variable Length Array

```
char natriz[filas][cols]; // <<--- VLA
```

Los arrays en C deben tener dimensiones conocidas en tiempo de compilación. Dado que  tanto `filas` como `cols` son variables, este requisito no se cumple.

Si el programa te compila es porque tu compilador hace uso de alguna extensión que permite los VLA, pero no es algo portable ni tampoco una estructura en la que debas confiar. Es preferible usar memoria dinámica:

```
char ** natriz = (char**)malloc(filas * sizeof(char*));
for( int i=0; i<filas; i++)
{
    natriz[i] = (char*)malloc(cols * sizeof(char));
}
```

Aunque analizando un poco el código se puede ver que este array no es necesario en absoluto. Puedes optar por generar la salida de la consola según iteras `matriz`:

```
    for(int i = 0; i< filas; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            char c = matriz[i][j] == 1 ? '*' : ' ';
            printf("%c ", c);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char natriz[filas][cols]; //creo matriz char para guardar los caraceteres '*' y ' '
> ```

No, no la creas. En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las matrices deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación; en otras palabras: el tamaño no puede ser una variable. Es más, no necesitas copiar la matriz recibida por parámetros en una matriz local para cambiar los unos y ceros por asteriscos y espacios, hazlo directamente:

```
int MatrizPintada(int filas,int cols,int matriz[filas][cols])
{
    for (int f = 0; f != filas; ++f)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c != cols; ++c)
        {
            printf("%c ", matriz[f][c] ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```